# JBOSS FUSE without Fuse MQ Details and Camel Details

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb, jbossfuse, fusefabric

I noticed on fabric container management console I couldn't find the Fuse MQ Details and Camel Details which is mentioned in JBOSS FUSE documentation.

Tried to add mq related profiles to the container, But I couldn't find the Fuse MQ Details and Camel Details button in the container details page.

Do I need to configure in anyother place to see the details.

I need to monitor the MQ in fabric container. But there is no details provided.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the full distribution of Jboss Fuse, then it comes with AMQ broker out of the box. If you use medium or minimal, then you would need to create a broker first.

You can see this video how to create and setup a broker
http://vimeo.com/album/2635012/video/84674508

Likewise Apache Camel is only visible in the container perspective if the container has Camel running inside it.

Although on the Fabric perspective in the runtime page, there is an EIP sub tab, you can click to see a visual node diagram of all the Camel running in the JVM.